# How to make a class to have an automatic implicit constructor like in the case of a record type?

Tags: c#

Following are examples of record:

Immutable - either of the following syntax:

```
public record Person(string FirstName, string LastName);


public record Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; init; } = default!;
    public string LastName { get; init; } = default!;
};
```

Mutable:

```
public record Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = default!;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = default!;
};
```

The record type can be instantiated using: `Person person = new("Nancy", "Davolio");`

Although I have not tried the following line, but I have seen online examples instantiating records like this also: `Person person = new Person("Nancy", "Davolio");`

So it looks like the record type provides an **implicit constructor** (that is - I didn't have to define a constructor).

How to make a class to have an automatic implicit constructor like this? Is this possible?

Comment: Are you asking about `new` without the type name?

Comment: No, this is about the ability of record to be able to instantiate without having user to define the constructor. Can we do this with a class?

Comment: That's called a "primary constructor" and it's limited to record types.

Comment: Calling that an "implicit constructor" is incorrect because you are explicitly telling the compiler that the class needs to be instantiated with those parameters.  The implementation is generated by the compiler, but it's not implicit. Default constructors that the compiler generates when there are no constructors defined, *those* are implicit.

Comment: Thanks mate. But is there any way to make a class have a feature like this at all?

Comment: As I said above, the feature is limited to record types.

Comment: I have a web api - in the response I have `return Ok (new {data = "some value"});`. Is it OK to create a record like this `public record MyResponse(string data);`; and then in the web api endpoint write `return Ok(new MyResponse("some value");` ? This is to avoid developer making mistakes when creating the anonymous object key value everytime

Comment: OK? That's opinion-based. Try it and see if it works.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what is the factor to consider in making the opinion

Comment: I personally approve of this idea. Too many anonymous types have varying shapes for the same purpose across a codebase and that becomes difficult to reconcile and maintain. That's my experience, anyway. But for your purposes, you need to try it out and see how it feels when you use it.

Comment: The thing is, you need to determine what your criteria are, then see if this pattern meets those criteria. Is the ceremony of declaring even a record type worth the consistency you gain? (for example) The best you can get here are high-minded ideals like "maintainability" and "consistency", but you need to narrow down what those mean for you.

Comment: My thinking about using the record type was that it saves me from writing and maintaining the constructor. In terms of memory utilization and scope per web request, record and class behave in the same way.

Comment: There is no way to declare a `class` with a primary constructor already in place. You will have to declare it for classes. Note that records are also classes "under the hood". A `record` is just a `class` with some bits provided by the compiler.

Comment: Maybe the answer to this question is to make use of Inheritance? The parent class defines the basic constructor and child class derives thereby auto inheriting the constructor?

Comment: No, constructors aren't inherited, so inheritance isn't a route forwards.

Comment: No, constructors aren't inherited in that way. If the base class has any constructors with parameters, the derived class will need to call one of them, which means it will likely have to accept those parameters in its own constructor.  That's *more* work, not less.

Comment: FYI that second `record` does not have a constructor that takes parameters.  Instead you'd have to do `Person person = new Person{FirstName = "Nancy", LastName = "Davolio"};`.  Basically when you define a record with the parameters directly after the name in parenthesis that's shorthand for defining the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: No it's not possible.

You can declare multiple constructors and do what you want in the default one.

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        // Here you can do what you want for default "settings"
    }

    public Person(string firstname, string lastname) : this()
    {
        Firstname = firstname;
        Lastname = lastname;
    }

    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```